# Loop doesn't unrar my files... Code doesn't enter into the loop

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ftplib, unrar

Morning Everybody,

I've a problem concerning my code. I'll explain, I've a connexion to a local FTP server on my linux instance. I would like to explore all my directories to unrar my files ".rar" but when I'm launching my script, there is just the display of directories that is working.

I don't know why.

```
def showDirectories(ftp):

  output=' /var/www/folder/Output'
  ftp.cwd('/FolderFiles')
  ftp.retrlines('LIST')
  directories = ftp.nlst()

  if directories not in ['..', '.']:
    i=0
    while i < len(directories):
      folder = directories[i]+'/'
      i+=1
      for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
          rarFiles=os.path.join(root, name)
          print(rarFiles)
          unrar = "unrar x "+rarFiles+output
          print("unrar commande"+str(unrar))
          download= os.system(unrar)
          print(download)
        ftp.cwd('..')
      print("")
```

Here the result:

```
[root@ip-10-0-2-52 folder]# python test.py
Connected! Welcome msg is "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)"
Connected !

drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0              90 Feb 11 14:42 DescriptiveData
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0              75 Feb 11 14:42 Financials
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0              87 Feb 11 14:42 OwnershipHisto
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: "if directories not in ['..', '.'];" Doesn't make sense in context.

Comment: Yes, it was just a debug line for test. I did this line in comment

Comment: Are you trying to use `os.walk` on the ftp side? Not sure if that is that easy; have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31465199/803359), though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for you help, finally I've found the solution to make my script work.

Here my updated

```
def downloadFile(path,target):

  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
      rarFiles=os.path.join(root, name)
      print(rarFiles)
      unrar = "unrar x "+rarFiles+target
      print("unrar commande"+str(unrar))
      download= os.system(unrar)
      print(download)

downloadFile('*****','*****')
```